# Prevent Node.js worker crash from propagating to main thread

Tags: node.js, worker

I'm using Node.js workers to run resources-intensive units of work in isolation, and to be able to keep the system alive in case one of them crashes badly.

However, when a Node.js worker crashes it seems to cause the main process to crash as well, and I could not find any way to avoid that.

To reproduce the issue, I set up a minimal test case using Node.js v19.7.0, where the worker forces a crash by indefinitely adding items to an array, while the main thread is kept busy using setInterval.

Any ideas?

`worker.js`

```
const a = []

while (true) {
    a.push('foobar')
}
```

`main.js`

```
const {Worker} = require('node:worker_threads')
const process = require('node:process')

// keep the main thread busy forever

setInterval(() => console.log('waiting...'), 1000)

// start the worker

const worker = new Worker('./worker.js')

// register process events listeners

process.on('beforeExit', (code) => {
    console.log('***** process:beforeExit', code)
})

process.on('exit', (code) => {
    console.log('***** process:exit', code)
})

process.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log('***** process:message', msg)
})

process.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('***** process:disconnect')
})

process.on('uncaughtException', (err, origin) => {
    console.log('***** process:uncaughtException', err, origin)
})

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
    console.log('***** process:unhandledRejection', promise, 'reason:', reason)
})

process.on('warning', (warning) => {
    console.warn('***** process:warning', warning)
})

// register worker events listeners

worker.on('online', () => {
    console.log('***** worker:online')
})

worker.on('exit', () => {
    console.log('***** worker:exit')
})

worker.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log('***** worker:message', msg)
})

worker.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('***** worker:error', err)
})

worker.on('messageerror', (err) => {
    console.error('***** worker:messageerror', err)
})
```

`log`

```
***** worker:online
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...


#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Fatal JavaScript invalid size error 169220804
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0x700005152310
 1: 0x10bb2c332 node::NodePlatform::GetStackTracePrinter()::$_3::__invoke()
 2: 0x10ce08db3 V8_Fatal(char const*, ...)
 3: 0x10be012e6 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArray(int, v8::internal::AllocationType)
 4: 0x10bff2c07 v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsAccessorBase<v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::FastPackedObjectElementsAccessor, v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsKindTraits<(v8::internal::ElementsKind)2> >::GrowCapacity(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, unsigned int)
 5: 0x10c286b56 v8::internal::Runtime_GrowArrayElements(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*)
 6: 0x10c6df3b9 Builtins_CEntry_Return1_DontSaveFPRegs_ArgvOnStack_NoBuiltinExit
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible solution towards the end of the thread: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/43331

Comment: The 'possible solution' doesn't work if you blow up the VM completely by having it run out of memory, which is what the code above does.  It will work for regular errors in the worker.  I'm not sure it's possible to recover if you run out of memory, but maybe someone knows more than me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use something like PM2 to restart the process ?

`npm install pm2 -g`

`pm2 start index.js`

`pm2 monit`